# Subtract a column in pandas dataframe by its first value

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, time, subtraction

I need to subtract all elements in one column of pandas dataframe by its first value.

In this code, pandas complains about self.inferred_type, which I guess is the circular referencing.

```
df.Time = df.Time - df.Time[0]
```

And in this code, pandas complains about setting value on copies.

```
df.Time = df.Time - df.iat[0,0]
```

What is the correct way to do this computation in Pandas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can select first item in column `Time` by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html):

```
df.Time = df.Time - df.Time.iloc[0]
```

Sample:

```
start = pd.to_datetime('2015-02-24 10:00')
rng = pd.date_range(start, periods=5)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': rng, 'a': range(5)})  
print (df)
                 Time  a
0 2015-02-24 10:00:00  0
1 2015-02-25 10:00:00  1
2 2015-02-26 10:00:00  2
3 2015-02-27 10:00:00  3
4 2015-02-28 10:00:00  4

df.Time = df.Time - df.Time.iloc[0]
print (df)
    Time  a
0 0 days  0
1 1 days  1
2 2 days  2
3 3 days  3
4 4 days  4
```

Notice:

For me works perfectly your 2 ways also.

Comment: Great! For me it's really strange that the warning of setting value on copy appears only once. Is df.Time a copy, or reference to the original dataframe?

Comment: I think reference, because cannot create new column this way - `df.newcol = df.Time - df.Time.iloc[0]`

Comment: And about warning - sometimes it happens. What is your version of pandas?

Comment: The version of pandas is 0.14.1.

Comment: Hmmm, it is really old. Now last is `0.19.0`. I think you can upgrade.

Comment: I still got the warning. It's really annoying, and I did: df.Time = df.Time  - 1. What is the code that avoid this warning (I don't want to turn warning off)?

Comment: Maybe help `df['Time'] = df.Time - 1` or `df['Time'] = df.Time.sub(1)`. But I think better is upgrade pandas.